# Highlight Text When Clicked

Tags: jquery

How can I highlight all the text within a textbox when it is clicked using jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me in both FF and IE.

```js
$("#user").click(function() {
  $("#user").focus();
  $("#user").select();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" value="username" id="user" />
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using jQuery to Highlight (Select) All Text in a Textbox**

http://www.willstrohl.com/Blog/tabid/66/EntryId/321/Using-jQuery-to-Highlight-Select-All-Text-in-a-Textbox.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
$('textarea').click(function() { this.focus(); this.select(); });
```

That should work for all textarea's - switch the selector if need be.

I would probably go with `class='autoselect'` and then `$('.autoselect')`

Answer (score 1):

Check out the JQuery UI 'highlight' effect at http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/

```
$( function() {
    $("textBoxId")
        .click( function(){
            var options = {};
            $("#textBoxId").effect("Highlight",options,500,callback);
        });
    });
```